# How can I adjust the Graph Editor?

Tags: animation

[image: blender guru]

I am following the donut beginner tutorial on youtube, when it´s about animation. The Graph Editor was introduced, but things look a little bit different on my try. Above is how it should look.[image: guru]

And here´s my turn. By scrolling the numbers get bigger, but that doesn´t solve the problem of not displaying a curve.
*Edit* I managed to zoom in to more reasonable numbers like in the tutorial but there is still no curve in the Graph Editor.

Comment: in your Graph Editor, look at the top bar, you are at frame 46500, maybe it's your problem? go back to frame 0

Comment: I went back to zero, but still no curves.

Comment: could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ws2ydd2d6vlfviu/donut_8_animation_share.blend?dl=0   the file is slightly bigger than 24MB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've enabled the *Normalize* option, it switches the vertical number bar from degrees to -1 to +1. Select the good track (*Z Rotation*) and zoom in a lot, you'll see the curve:

[image]

Comment: Okay  thanks, I can see the curve now, but it starts around 120 vertical. When I move the curve to the negative area it plays backwards.

Comment: I'm not sure what you've done, in the Graph Editor select the curve and move it on the Y axis until it starts at the degree you want. If it still doesn't work please share your file again

Answer (score 0):

Like in most editors that have a notion of adaptable view, you have a `View` menu, allowing you to control that.

[image: View Menu]

And the shortcuts for these controls are the same in all these editors.

And like most editors, you can use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> to zoom in and out. This results in a simple zoom in the viewport and most other editors,
but the Graph editor will resize its interface on both X and Y axes depending on how you move your mouse up/down or left/right:

[image: demo zoom]

Comment: Nah, sadly that didn´t help.

Comment: Have you tried "Frame All" ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have *Only Selected* selected (little arrow on the right-hand side of the *Normalize* button). If  you have only the first keyframe selected and this button pressed you will not see the graph lines. Uncheck it to see them.